# I want to draw circle around my location

Tags: android

I want to draw circle around my location . and find out other user location and want to see dat users are in my range or not.

Comment: Please at least show you've made some effort to solve your problem - I've had a quick peek at your question history, and you seem to be asking for step-by-step instructions on all things GPS

Comment: i have did all by own...mostly i didnt get any answer from here....i had done by own..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to look into a fair few things here.

1. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html to get the users location
2. http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html to draw locations on the map

That should give you enough to get your location on a map. As for finding other users you will probably have to set up a server that your application posts users locations to and then shares them between all users. This is a bit of a big topic to cover without more information.